# Verificador de idade

Tags: input

Estou desenvolvendo essa aplicação em JavaScript para verificar a idade,  e mudar a cor de fundo e foto conforme a situação do usuário. Um dos problemas que estou tendo é com o botão VER, entre outros erros que não consigo identificar.

```js
function Ver(){
  var nome = window.document.getElementById('camponome').value
  var nasc = window.document.getElementById('camponasc').value
  var res = window.document.getElementById('res')
        var foto = window.document.getElementById('foto')
  var data = new Date()
  var ano = data.getfullyear()
  if (nasc.value.length == 0 || Number(nasc.value) > ano) {
   window.alert('[ERRO] verifique os dados e tente novamente !')
  } else {
  var sexo = window.document.getElementById('radsex').value
  var idade = ano - Number(nasc.value)
  var genero = ''
  if (sexo[0].checked) {
   genero = 'homem'
   if (idade >= 0 && idade <= 3) {
    // bebe
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'blue'
    foto.src = 'img/bebe_menino.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 4 && idade <= 12) {
    // criança
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'green'
    foto.src = 'img/crianca_menino.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 13 && idade <= 17) {
    // adolescente
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#3f1866'
    foto.src = 'img/adolescente_menino.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 40) {
    // adulto
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#757575'
    foto.src = 'img/adulto.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 41 && idade <= 59) {
    // coroa
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'yellow'
    foto.src = 'img/homem_coroa.jpg'
   } else {
    // idoso
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'red'
    foto.src = 'img/idoso.jpg'
   }
  } else if (sexo[1].checked) {
   genero = 'mulher'
   if (idade >= 0 && idade <= 3) {
    // bebe
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'pink'
    foto.src = 'img/bebe_menina.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 4 && idade <= 12) {
    // criança
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'green'
    foto.src = 'img/crianca_menina.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 13 && idade <= 17) {
    // adolescente
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#3f1866'
    foto.src = 'img/adolescente_menina.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 40) {
    // adulto
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#757575'
    foto.src = 'img/adulta.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 41 && idade <= 59) {
    // coroa
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'yellow'
    foto.src = 'img/mulher_coroa.jpg'
   } else {
    // idoso
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'red'
    foto.src = 'img/idosa.jpg'
   }
  }
  }

  res.innerHTML = `Olá ${nome} seu sexo é ${genero} com ${idade} anos`
 
 }
```

```css
body{
   background: black;
  }
  header{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
            -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
            -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
            font-size: 1.5em; 
  }
  section{
   background: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 580px;
            height: 390px;
            margin: auto;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  }
  section #nome{
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
   border-radius: 15px;
  }
  section #nasc{
   position: absolute;
   top: 110px;
   border-radius: 15px;
  }
  section #sexo{
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
   right: 380px;
  }
  section #Ver{
   position: absolute;
   top: 105px;
   right: 450px;
   margin: 25px auto;
            border-radius: 15px;
            size: 30px;
  }
  section #res{
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 650px;
   
  }
  section #img{
   position: absolute;
   top: 120px;
   left: 280px;
  }
  footer{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Formulario</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 
</head>
<body>
 
 <!-- Cabeçalho -->
<header id="header" class="">
 <p>
 Formulario 
 </p> 
</header>

<section id="formulario">
 
 <p id="nome">
  Nome :
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="camponome"> 
 </p>
 <p id="sexo">
  Qua o seu sexo ?
  <input type="radio" name="radsex" value="masc" checked>
   <label for="masc">Masculino</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radsex" value="fem">
   <label for="fem">Feminino</label>
 </p>
 <p id="nasc">
  Ano de nascimento :
  <input type="number" name="camponasc" id="camponasc" min="0">
 </p>
 <div>
  <input type="button" value="verificar" id="Ver" onclick="Ver()">
 </div>
 <p id="img">
  <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="foto" id="foto">
 </p>
 <p id="res">
  Resultado
 </p>

</section>

<footer>
   <p>&copy; SamuelMoreira3</p> 
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os erros são que `.getFullYear()` está com sintaxe errada, está tudo em minúsculo:

```
var ano = data.getfullyear()
```

Os outros erros é que a variável `nasc` já pega o valor e você está tentando pegar novamente no `if` e na variável `idade`:

```
// declaração da variável
var nasc = window.document.getElementById('camponasc').value
                                                         ↑

// o if
if (nasc.value.length == 0 || Number(nasc.value) > ano) {
           ↑                                ↑

// e aqui também
var idade = ano - Number(nasc.value)
                                ↑
```

Outro erro é na linha:

```
var sexo = window.document.getElementById('radsex').value
```

O `radsex` são dois radios com `name="radsex"` e não `id`. Logo você deveria pegar pelo `name` e não pelo `id`:

```
var sexo = window.document.getElementsByName('radsex')
```

Com essas correções seu código passa a funcionar:

```js
function Ver(){
  var nome = window.document.getElementById('camponome').value
  var nasc = window.document.getElementById('camponasc').value
  var res = window.document.getElementById('res')
        var foto = window.document.getElementById('foto')
  var data = new Date()
  var ano = data.getFullYear()
  if (nasc.length == 0 || Number(nasc) > ano) {
   window.alert('[ERRO] verifique os dados e tente novamente !')
  } else {
  var sexo = window.document.getElementsByName('radsex')
  var idade = ano - Number(nasc)
  var genero = ''
  if (sexo[0].checked) {
   genero = 'homem'
   if (idade >= 0 && idade <= 3) {
    // bebe
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'blue'
    foto.src = 'img/bebe_menino.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 4 && idade <= 12) {
    // criança
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'green'
    foto.src = 'img/crianca_menino.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 13 && idade <= 17) {
    // adolescente
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#3f1866'
    foto.src = 'img/adolescente_menino.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 40) {
    // adulto
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#757575'
    foto.src = 'img/adulto.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 41 && idade <= 59) {
    // coroa
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'yellow'
    foto.src = 'img/homem_coroa.jpg'
   } else {
    // idoso
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'red'
    foto.src = 'img/idoso.jpg'
   }
  } else if (sexo[1].checked) {
   genero = 'mulher'
   if (idade >= 0 && idade <= 3) {
    // bebe
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'pink'
    foto.src = 'img/bebe_menina.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 4 && idade <= 12) {
    // criança
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'green'
    foto.src = 'img/crianca_menina.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 13 && idade <= 17) {
    // adolescente
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#3f1866'
    foto.src = 'img/adolescente_menina.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 18 && idade <= 40) {
    // adulto
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = '#757575'
    foto.src = 'img/adulta.jpg'
   } else if (idade >= 41 && idade <= 59) {
    // coroa
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'yellow'
    foto.src = 'img/mulher_coroa.jpg'
   } else {
    // idoso
    res.innerHTML = `A sua idade é ${idade} anos.`
    document.body.style.background = 'red'
    foto.src = 'img/idosa.jpg'
   }
  }
  }

  res.innerHTML = `Olá ${nome} seu sexo é ${genero} com ${idade} anos`
 
 }
```

```css
body{
   background: black;
  }
  header{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
            -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.5px;
            -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
            font-size: 1.5em; 
  }
  section{
   background: white;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 15px;
            padding: 15px;
            width: 580px;
            height: 390px;
            margin: auto;
            box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px black;
  }
  section #nome{
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
   border-radius: 15px;
  }
  section #nasc{
   position: absolute;
   top: 110px;
   border-radius: 15px;
  }
  section #sexo{
   position: absolute;
   top: 80px;
   right: 380px;
  }
  section #Ver{
   position: absolute;
   top: 105px;
   right: 450px;
   margin: 25px auto;
            border-radius: 15px;
            size: 30px;
  }
  section #res{
   position: absolute;
   top: 200px;
   left: 650px;
   
  }
  section #img{
   position: absolute;
   top: 120px;
   left: 280px;
  }
  footer{
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>Formulario</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 
</head>
<body>
 
 <!-- Cabeçalho -->
<header id="header" class="">
 <p>
 Formulario 
 </p> 
</header>

<section id="formulario">
 
 <p id="nome">
  Nome :
  <input type="text" name="nome" id="camponome"> 
 </p>
 <p id="sexo">
  Qua o seu sexo ?
  <input type="radio" name="radsex" value="masc" checked>
   <label for="masc">Masculino</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radsex" value="fem">
   <label for="fem">Feminino</label>
 </p>
 <p id="nasc">
  Ano de nascimento :
  <input type="number" name="camponasc" id="camponasc" min="0">
 </p>
 <div>
  <input type="button" value="verificar" id="Ver" onclick="Ver()">
 </div>
 <p id="img">
  <img src="img/user.jpg" alt="foto" id="foto">
 </p>
 <p id="res">
  Resultado
 </p>

</section>

<footer>
   <p>&copy; SamuelMoreira3</p> 
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: muito obrigado amigão !

Comment: Se resolveu, marque a resposta, jovem. Abs